# Show that the limit $\lim_{z\to 0} e^{-1/z}$ does not exist

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Show that the limit  $\lim_{z\to 0} e^{-1/z}$ does not exist

Along real axis putting $z=x+i0$,

we have $\lim_{z\to 0} e^{-1/z}=\lim_{x\to 0} e^{-1/x}=-\infty$

Along imaginary axis putting $z=0+iy$,

we have $\lim_{z\to 0} e^{-1/z}=\lim_{y\to 0} e^{-1/iy}=\lim_{y\to 0} e^{i/y}=\infty$

I.e two different approach to $z=0$ give two different limit, so limit does not exist.

Is the proof correct?

Second evaluation of limit is correct? ($\lim_{y\to 0} e^{-1/iy}=\lim_{y\to 0} e^{i/y}=\infty$ )

Is there any other method to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to consider z real.
$$lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{- \frac{1}{x}}=0$$
$$lim_{x \to 0^-} e^{- \frac{1}{x}}= \infty$$
So the limit does not exist.

I should also probably point out a couple of errors in your proof:
1. When you take the real limit, you should notice that x approaching from the negative and positive directions give different answers, so saying $lim_{x \to 0} e^{- \frac{1}{x}}= \infty$ isn't correct.
2. When you take the imaginary limit, the answer is not $\infty$. $y$ is real so as $y \to 0$ all that's happening is $e^{i/y}$ is spinning round the unit circle in the complex plane, still not converging to anything, but also not tending to infinity.